# Parse others classes with same body use retrofit

Tags: java, android

i have the follow json

```
{
    "Timestamp": "00:01",
    "Value": {
        "101": {
            "ID": "252551",
            "NumCode": "101"
        },
        "102": {
            "ID": "252552",
            "NumCode": "102"
        },
        "103": {
            "ID": "252553",
            "NumCode": "103"
        },
        "104": {
            "ID": "252554",
            "NumCode": "104"
        }
    }
    }
```

if i use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org it create for each "value" body new class. but i see that body of them class is equels. how i can create generic class for value body? i wanna use the Retrofit 2

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("Timestamp")
@Expose
private String timestamp;
@SerializedName("Value")
@Expose
private Value value;

//getters + setters

}
///////////////
public class Value {

@SerializedName("101")
@Expose
private com.example._101 _101;
@SerializedName("102")
@Expose
private com.example._102 _102;
@SerializedName("103")
@Expose
private com.example._103 _103;
@SerializedName("104")
@Expose
private com.example._104 _104;

//getters + setters
}
```

Comment: use gson Converter and correct your JSON format. (Gson converter better fits with retrofit)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the structure of json if you want to use a common class . Use a json array for values instead of json object . what ever 101,102 etc keep them inside object

Here is the sample json format you need to follow

```
{
    "Timestamp": "00:01",
    "Value": [
        {
            "ID": "252551",
            "NumCode": "101"
        },
         {
            "ID": "252552",
            "NumCode": "102"
        },
         {
            "ID": "252553",
            "NumCode": "103"
        },
        {
            "ID": "252554",
            "NumCode": "104"
        }
     ]
  }
```

This will be the object
**Example.java**

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("Timestamp")
public String timestamp;
@SerializedName("Value")
public List<Value> value = null;

}
```

**Value.java**

```
public class Value {

@SerializedName("ID")
public String iD;
@SerializedName("NumCode")
public String numCode;

}
```